# Tableau Calculated Field error

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a calculated field in tableau. Below is my code:

`IF MONTH(date)=1 THEN CP*0.1
ELSEIF MONTH(date)=2 THEN CP*0.2
ELSE CP
ENDIF`

but i keep getting an error message "expected END to match IF at character 0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `END` instead of `ENDIF`...

```
IF MONTH(date)=1 THEN CP*0.1
ELSEIF MONTH(date)=2 THEN CP*0.2
ELSE CP
END
```